# Can't understand &(sizeof 2[a])[a]

Tags: c, arrays, string

I've got some code that outputs `bcdefg` and I can't understand why.

I google searched but I couldn't find anything.

```
const char a[]="Abcdefg";
printf("%s",&(sizeof 2[a])[a]);
```

Why is the output `bcdefg`, and not `Abcdefg`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is meant to confuse you, not do anything useful. Don't write code like this. Here is how it is interpreted by the compiler:

- `2[a]` is the same as `a[2]`, which is a value of `char` type (which value exactly doesn't matter; the compiler even doesn't try to evaluate it)
- `sizeof 2[a]` is the same as `sizeof(char)`, which is equal to 1
- `&(sizeof 2[a])[a]` is a pointer to the character `b` in the string `Abcdef` - the one which has the index 1
- `printf("%s",&(sizeof 2[a])[a])` prints the string, starting at that pointer

Answer (score 5):

Referring to the code excerpt:

```
printf("%s",&(sizeof 2[a])[a]);
```

First, most people don't realize it, but the `[]` operator it actually commutative.  `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)`, which is equivalent to `*(b + a)`, which is equivalent to `b[a]`.

So `2[a]` is equivalent to `a[2]`.  Since `a` has type `const char []`, the size of an element is the same as `sizeof(char)`, which is 1.

So we now have:

```
printf("%s",&1[a]);
```

Well, `1[a]` is equivalent to `a[1]`, or `*(a + 1)`.  Applying the address-of operator gives `&a[1]`, or `a + 1` (note that `&*x` is just `x`).

So we have:

```
printf("%s", a + 1);
```

This just prints the string pointed to by `a + 1`, i.e. everything after the first character of `a`.

If you just reorder the `[]` operators without doing anything else, you can see that it's equivalent to:

```
printf("%s", &a[sizeof a[2]]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you break down each segment:

```cs
&(sizeof 2[a])[a]

2[a] = a[2].  a[2] = a char element at position 2

sizeof(char) = 1

(1)[a] = a[1]

&(a[1]) = a reference to the 'b' in "bcdefg"
```

printf() then prints the char array starting with b and ending at the null terminator

Comment: In C, `sizeof('c')` is only 1 on systems where `sizeof(int)` is 1.

Comment: Good to know, I updated the answer to be "sizeof(char) = 1" which I am hoping is the correct edit